# How to query for documents that have a subdocument meeting a criteria in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, meteor

I have a filter section page on my website. I'm using Meteor and I want to show all the Albums/EPS/Singles that have at least one song that meets price criteria.

A sample album/EP/Single document would look as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "gj92wpjw5WNfkgDJd",
    "title" : "Gem",
    "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "isExplicit" : false,
    "releaseDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T13:27:08.483Z"),
    "ownedBy" : {
        "user" : "AAPrkjkPtn8nbmYbM",
        "accountDataId" : "njJyhGfLGb83oztmT",
        "name" : "Zia Cecille",
        "path" : "/artist/zia-cecille"
    },
    "mood" : {
        "energetic" : 50,
        "happy" : 50,
        "electronic" : 50,
        "vocal" : 50
    },
    "songs" : [ 
        "E6FwMr9FcwEYM79wt", 
        "KXQmvr7QMGX9q6u7C", 
        "oasNrffNbiZXQ9WEJ"
    ],
    "isPublished" : true,
    "isDisplayedOnSite" : true,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-08-14T13:27:08.483Z")
}
```

The songs property is an array of all songs subdocument belonging to that Album/EP/Single. Each song is a separate document, part of another Songs collection. How do I query for Albums/EP/Singles that has at least one song filtered by Price?

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question, I queried in the Songs collection for all songs matching a price filter value and returned an array from that query. Then I queried in the Albums/EP/Singles using the $in operator for any documents that contains any of the values inside the former array of queried songs.